# C# Setting CultureInfo based on QueryString parameter and resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cultureinfo

I have a web application that simply displays a form User Control. I have generated my **resx** files associated with the User Control by going to the design of the User Control and then clicking **Tools > Generate Local Resource**

Doing this has created the necessary **resx** file:

```
App_LocalResources
  ContactUsForm.ascx.resx
```

I then simply copy and pasted the existing **resx** file and renamed it so I now have the following:

```
App_LocalResources
  ContactUsForm.ascx.fr-FR.resx
  ContactUsForm.ascx.resx
```

As a test I modified a couple of the dotnet controls text within the new **fr-FR** resource file just to test whether it was all working as expected and it is not.

I use the following code to set the specific culture information based on a querystring parameter:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cultureName = Request.QueryString["lang"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureName))
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
    }
}
```

I can then simply navigate to the page housing the user control by doing the following:

http://localhost/Default.aspx?lang=fr-FR

I can confirm the culture information is being set by executing the following code:

```
CultureInfo currentCultureUI = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
```

I can confirm that the set culture is in fact **fr-FR** however the text is not being replaced as per the changes within the **ContactUsForm.ascx.fr-FR.resx** file.

I can't seem to get this working as expected. What am I doing wrong and is there any other way to achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

If I do the following in code it works just fine:

```
lHeadingResource1.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("lHeadingResource1.Text").ToString();
```

It's actually reading the correct string from the **ContactUsForm.ascx.fr-FR.resx** file.

I can also confirm that my controls have all the necessary `meta:resourcekey` references as well.

It's just strange that if I don't set it in code it defaults back to the default culture and doesn't use the **fr-FR** specified above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the culture by overriding the Page's InitializeCulture method.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request.Form["DropDownList1"] != null)
    {
        //define the language
        UICulture = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
        //define the formatting (requires a specific culture)
        Culture = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

The page here http://blogs.spanlogic.com/clyap/post/2009/05/29/Programmatically-change-Culture-of-User-Control-(ascx).aspx suggests you can use FrameworkInitialize inside a user control. I haven't tested this tho.

```
    protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
    {
        base.FrameworkInitialize();
    }
```

Comment: I suspect any code in the user control will execute too late in the page life cycle to correctly load the resource file. InitializeCulture runs before Page_Init. Both of which are before any events are fired on the user control.

Comment: `protected override void FrameworkInitialize()` did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
You have to implement your logic with InitializeCulture()

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" uiculture="auto" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<script runat="server">

    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Request.Form["ListBox1"] != null)
        {
            String selectedLanguage = Request.Form["ListBox1"];
            UICulture = selectedLanguage ;
            Culture = selectedLanguage ;

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
                CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
        }
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
</script>
```

For More Info Refer Below Link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.80).aspx